# Xdocument, Xelement.Save incorrect encoding

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-signature

I 'm having problem with the code presented:

```
string serializedLicence = SerializationHelper.ToXML(licenceInfo);
var licenceFileXml = new XElement("Licence", new XElement("LicenceData", serializedLicence)));
XmlDocument signedLicence = SignXml(licenceFileXml.ToString(), Properties.Resources.PRIVATE_KEY);
signedLicence.Save(saveFileDialogXmlLicence.FileName);
```

The created file has an incorrect coding of strings send to XElement constructors aswell as the signature, that assigned with custom `SignXml()` method (which creates signature with `XmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild()` method, but that's irrelevant right now). The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>
<Licence>
    <LicenceData>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
    &lt;LicenceInfo
    //stuff stuff stuff
    &lt;/LicenceInfo&gt;</LicenceData>
    <Signature>&lt;SignedInfo xmlns="h stuff stuff stuff</Signature>
</Licence>
```

So basically I'm taking serialized object string and put it between  markers, and this part gets encoded wrong. Debugger shows me, that the text in XElement object is holding `&lt;` and `&gt;` just after creating it. I could parse it manually, but that's inapropriate.

Note: befeore that, I was straight signing the deserialisation xml and it worked fine, so I can't figure it out why `XDocument` uses different encoding than `XmlSerializer`/`XmlDocument` object.

Also: I think I could just use `XmlDocument` object to build the file, but I'm curious what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding `serializedLicence` as `string`, so it's treated as text, not as XML and that's why it looks like that in you document.

```
var licenceFileXml = new XElement("Licence",
                         new XElement("LicenceData",
                             XDocument.Parse(serializedLicence).Root)));
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to xml and I did not expected, that the string between node's markers is supposed to be parsed. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Tarec It has to be parsed because otherwise you wouldn't get proper structure of `XElement`/`XAttribute` instances, which represent the XML.